# Formik react form get value of field on change

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I am using Formik for react form with material UI.
I have two fields and I need to do the calculation on that two fields as value change, so I must get the value of those two fields,

```
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            quantity: '',
            price: '',
            total: '',
        },
        validationSchema: Yup.object({
            quantity: Yup.string().max(5).required('Quantity is required'),
            price: Yup.string().max(5).required('Price is required'),
        }),
        onSubmit: values => {

        },
    })
```

And here is form

```
<form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
    <TextField
        type="number"
        size="small"
        error={Boolean(
            formik.touched.quantity && formik.errors.quantity,
        )}
        helperText={
            formik.touched.quantity && formik.errors.quantity
        }
        label="Quantity"
        margin="normal"
        name="quantity"
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.quantity}
        variant="outlined"
    />
    <TextField
        size="small"
        error={Boolean(formik.touched.price && formik.errors.price)}
        helperText={formik.touched.price && formik.errors.price}
        label="Last Name"
        margin="normal"
        name="price"
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        value={formik.values.price}
        variant="outlined"
    />

    {Boolean(
        formik.touched.tax_status && formik.errors.tax_status,
    ) && (
        <FormHelperText error>
            {formik.errors.tax_status}
        </FormHelperText>
    )}
    <Box sx={{ py: 2 }}>
        <Button
            color="primary"
            disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
            fullWidth
            size="large"
            type="submit"
            variant="contained">
            Submit
        </Button>
    </Box>
</form>
```

How to retrieve values of quantity and price on every change?

Comment: I haven't use formik so not sure, maybe you can put a useEffect on your `formik.values` and then do whatever you want with it?

Comment: I'll put this in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't use formik so not sure, maybe you can put an `useEffect` on your `formik.values` and then do whatever you want with it.

Something like

```js
useEffect(()=>{

    //do your stuff

},[formik.vaues])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna show the result on the form, you can just add something like that in your code;

```
<div>{formik.values.price} * {formik.values.quantity}</div>
```

If you wanna do some validation, you can update your validation schema

```
validationSchema: Yup.object({
  quantity: Yup.string().max(5).required('Quantity is required'),
  price: Yup.string().max(5)
    .required('Price is required')
    .when('quantity', (quantity, schema) => (quantity && schema.test(
      'limit',
      'some message',
      value => {
        return (value && value + quantity > 30) // condition
      }
    ))),
```

Comment: Yes this also perefect.

Comment: How to use this without useFormik, because as per documentation some components like ```<FieldArray>``` doesn't work. so if we just use ```<Formik>``` how to get values and set to another field?

Comment: https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void  you can use setFieldValue(), it takes value name and value.